# Does anyone know of a good library for mapping a person's name to his or her gender?

Tags: database, language-agnostic

I am looking for a library or database that can provide guesses about whether a person is male or female based on his or her name or nickname.  Something like

```
john => "M",
mary => "F",
alex => "A", #ambiguous
```

I am looking for something that supports names other than English names (such as Japanese, Indian, etc.).

Before I get another answer along the lines of "you are going to offend people by assuming their sex/gender" let me be clear, my application does not interact with anyone.  It does not send emails or contact anyone in anyway.  There are no users to ask.  In many cases, the person in question is dead, and the only information I have is name, birth date, and date of death.  The reason I want to know the sex of the individual is to make the grammar of the output nicer and to aid in possible searches that may come latter.

Comment: Could you give us more details about what do you need the mapping for?

Comment: The question doesn't ask for programming, it asks for a database. The answers aren't programming -- some are non-answers and some are databases. I agree with a lot of the non-answers but that's just personal opinion. The point is that this isn't a programming question and there are no programming answers.

Comment: chas, it's not the thing that people don't want to give you that because of a moral thing, it's like it has no sense in the beginning, so you're asking for a fail solution. also, you mentione other than english names, and in cross-cultural reference, it gets even more complicated. for me, it's a no go.

Comment: Chas, it seems most of the answers and comments assume (because you haven't specified) that you're guessing the sex of someone that your software will then be interacting with. If that's not true, please update the question to make your requirements clearer.

Comment: I agree that there are two issues with this question: 1. The assumption that better than 50% is good. I'd say ask your average female Chris and male Su whether or not they enjoy being mis-addressed 100% of the time. 2. That there are only two genders in the world. Sure, we've been taught that, but it really doesn't reflect reality.

Comment: Note that I am specifically looking for sex, not gender.  This is one of the reasons I have resisted the changing of the question to refer to gender instead of sex.  Also, for someone concerned about assumptions you are making one.  If you read the comments you will see that nothing is being sent to the people whose names are being examined, so there us no possibility of offense.

Comment: Why not introduce the person and then use 'they/their' to refer to a male or female?

Comment: Then I'm baffled by what you are trying to accomplish.  I'm not aware of any standard, tool, dataset, algorithm, or SWAG that can get you from a given name to that.

"Note that I am specifically looking for sex"

Okie dokie.  On that note, I'll leave this up to you to sort out - ON YOUR OWN.

Comment: @Nick Presta Because then my English professor wife would strangle me.

Comment: @Chas: how accurate is your database in terms of spelling (or transliterating) names? In particular, how accurate are you in the spelling of names from languages that do not use the Latin alphabet? If you're going to start off with bad transliterations, then you're going to wind up with bad mappings to gender.

Comment: Two I learned recently: Napolean is male. LaFonda is female (or perhaps a guy in drag).

Comment: @John Saunders: "bad mappings to gender" -- sex (male, female, etc) is not the same thing as gender (masculine, feminine, etc). Are you being needlessly polite again? :)

Comment: Please...  Don't waste our time posting ignorant answers like this.  If you're baffled or don't like the question... MOVE ALONG.  If you read the question, he's trying to make nicer output, by attaching a "sex" (him/her, male/female, penis/vagina) to a name, so that anything written about an individual reads nicer without complicated "him or her" or gender neutral phrases.  The name owners do not see this and therefore cannot be offended.  In other words, it only has to been good enough so as to not be obviously wrong, like referring to to "Dick", "Bob", or "Tom" as "she" or "her".

Comment: How can you tell if a name is male or female? Alex could be short for Alexander (a male) or Alexandra (a female). I know a Micah who is male and one who is female. And what about foreign names?

Comment: Something to watch out for is that name use sometimes changes with time, so if you do use an historical database, bear this in mind.

Comment: @Chas. Owens: [Singular “they” and the many reasons why it’s correct](http://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/singular-they-and-the-many-reasons-why-its-correct/)

Comment: @Paul Ruane++ regarding historical trends. 50+ years ago my given name was exclusively masculine, now it's primarily feminine. There are many other examples of this particular switch.

Comment: [This page on Open Data SX has some related answers][1]


  [1]: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/46/multinational-list-of-popular-first-names-and-surnames

Comment: The OpenGenderTracking project has some useful resouces. Although compiled from UK and USA data, it seems to cover worldwide names. Respective CSV data [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenGenderTracking/globalnamedata/master/assets/ukprocessed.csv) and [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenGenderTracking/globalnamedata/master/assets/usprocessed.csv).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The gender of a name is something that cannot be inferred programmatically in the general case. You need a name database. <strike>Here is [a free name database from the US Census Bureau](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/names_files.html).</strike>

**EDIT**: The link for the 2010 name is dead but there are working links and a libraries in the comments.

Comment: Saw this in first.dist.males "HAI            0.004 90.022   1214"

Comment: Unknown, I'm not sure what you mean. A quick Google search shows that Hai is a boy name of Hebrew origin.

Comment: it's not a name that translates well to English.. not Hai but more like Chai, or if you go by the Alphabet, Jai.

Comment: Here's name -> gender from census data as python dict: https://raw.github.com/Bemmu/gender-from-name/master/gender.py

Comment: I don't know why they keep moving it around, but if you search the census site for "surnames" it shows up in the results.  The current location is now here...  https://www.census.gov/topics/population/genealogy/data/1990_census/1990_census_namefiles.html  I'm going to stop updating this if it changes -- knowing it exists should make it google-able if it moves again; google "census names files" for mirrors and applications

Comment: 22MB of US baby names with gender by year of birth: http://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/limits.html  (link valid at July 2015)

Comment: I found this MySQL database which should have about 100000 names with gender information: (https://github.com/guydavis/babynamemap/blob/master/db.sql.gz)

Answer (score 70):

gender.c is an **open source** C program that does a good job.
It comes with data for 44568 first names from all around the world.
There is good documentation and a description of the file format (basically plain text)
so it should not be to difficult to read it from your own application.

Here is what the author says:

> A few words on quality of data
>
> The dictionary of first names has been prepared with utmost care.
> For example, the Turkish, Indian and Korean names in this dictionary
> have all been independently classified by several native speakers.
> I also took special care to list only those names which can currently
> be found.
>
> The lesson from this?
>
> Any modifications should be done very cautiously (and they must also
> adhere to the sorting required by the search algorithm).
> For example, knowing that "Sascha" is a boy's name in Germany,
> the author never assumed the English "Sasha" to be a girl's name.
> Knowing that "Jan" is a boy's name in Germany, I never assumed it to be
> also a English short form of "Janet".
> Another case in point is the name "Esra". This is a boy's name in
> Germany, but a girl's name in Turkey.

The program calculates a probability for the name being male of female.
It can do so with the name as input alone or with the name and country of origin,
which gives significantly better results.

You can download it from the website of the German computer magazine c't
[40 000 Namen](http://www.heise.de/ct/ftp/07/17/182/).
The article is in German but don't worry, all documentation is English.
Here is the direct ftp link [0717-182.zip](ftp://ftp.heise.de/pub/ct/listings/0717-182.zip) if you are not interested in the article.
The zip-File contains the source code, an windows executable, the database
and the documentation.

Comment: See here for the python port - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SexMachine/

Answer (score 33):

"I tell ya, life ain't easy for a boy named 'Sue.'"

...So, why make it any harder? If you need to know the sex, just ask... Otherwise, don't worry about it.

Comment: That works when you are in communication with the person, but we make assumptions about sex all the time, and it has an affect on grammar, so it would be nice if I could make even an 80% stab at getting the pronouns right.  Right now I am right fiftyish percent of the time using "he", but that seems sexist to me, and I want to make it better.

Comment: @Chas: even if you manage to get it right 80% of the time, that's still gonna irritate two out of every ten people using your software. Not so good... I understand the motivation, but you're really better off re-wording your messages such that they're gender-neutral.

Comment: I wonder if anyone else remembers "Pat" from SNL.

Comment: Re-reading this, i'm coming off awful preachy... Don't mean to put down your idea, i think it's an interesting one... But also very risky. I used to work as a telemarketer, and no matter how many names you know, no matter how good you get at recognizing voices even, you still end up guessing wrong sometimes... and it's never fun. And so, it's something i would avoid, unless there's a big, big payoff for managing to guess it *right*.

Comment: I would take Shog9's advise. Unless your application is going to be in languages other than English, it might be easier to just use gender-neutral pronouns--e.g. they, one, s/he, etc.

Comment: I can totally see the benefit of this. In my home country, a lot of marketing companies get address lists from the high schools but without gender info, so they used to try and figure out genders from first names. I had a male friend with a very female name that regularly got samples of female hygiene products.

Comment: My girlfriend's name is Kevan. She gets enough people wrongly guessing her gender from her name, she doesn't need computers also doing it. The thing to beware of is creating a database entry that states someone's gender based on a computer's guess; people who look at that might assume it's provided by the person themselves, and get really confused when their assumptions turn out to be wrong (as opposed to only somewhat confused based on the name alone).

Comment: re: "Just ask". C'mon, what's more practical, spam 100000 people with "Please tell us your gender" email or use a mapping database on data you already have? Especially when all you need is a nice piechart for marketing.

Comment: @Constantin: sure - if you're not going to try to change the experience of any user based on the data, then use whatever means of creating that data you feel like. Heck, if accuracy doesn't really matter, then just make it up...

Comment: Maybe he's trying to de-prioritize the obvious ones so that he could set the Ambiguous names to a higher priority ... like people doing data entry. There are valid reasons of doing something like this.

Comment: If you do it in a subtle way this would boost usability too. for example: put the name inputs first, hit the server with an ajax request and set the gender field (which is near the end) to the "best guess"

Comment: I'm implementing it to choose the voice of an IVR to be the opposite sex of the user. If you guess wrong, who cares, but if you guess right, you could get a boost to retention and reduction of call volume to live agents.

Comment: it is very odd that this question received any positive votes, e.g. perhaps one is a data analyst and wants to compare client satisfaction scores between account managers and gender of their clients, i.e. do female AMs with female clients have scores different than male AMs with female clients? If there are thousands of clients it isn't practical to just ask the gender.

Answer (score 30):

I've builded a free API that gives a probabilistic guess on the gender based on a first name. Instead of using any of the above mentioned approaches, i instead use a huge dataset of profiles from social networks to provide a probabilistic guess along with a certainty factor. It also supports optional filtering through country or language id's. It's getting better by the day as more profiles are added to the dataset.

It's free to use at http://genderize.io

**ONE** thing you should consider is using a tool that takes demographics into account, as naming conventions will rely heavily on this.

Example

```
http://api.genderize.io?name=kim
{"name":"kim","gender":"female","probability":"0.89","count":1440}

http://api.genderize.io?name=kim&country_id=dk
{"name":"kim","gender":"male","probability":"0.95","count":44,"country_id":"dk"}
```

Comment: Code extensions - http://genderize.io/#extensions

Answer (score 22):

Here are two oddball approaches that may not even work, and likely wouldn't work en masse without violating the terms of a license:

1. Use the Facebook API (which I know virtually nothing about, it may not even be possible) to perform two searches: one for FB male users with that first name, and one for female. Use the two numbers to decide the probability of gender.
2. Much looser but more scalable, use the Google API and search for the name plus the gender-specific pronouns, and compare the numbers. For instance, there are 592,000,000 results for searching for "Richard his" (not as a phrase), but only 179,000,000 for "Richard her".

Comment: Apart from the general consensus on having software trying to guess things like sex from a first name, this is really cool algorithmic answer to the original question. Well done.

Comment: Great idea. You can probably throw in some words in a given country's language as well to localize it.

Comment: Good point, Nosrenda... of course, Google also allows you to filter search results by language code already. You can even steal the user's preferred language from the HTTP request. Their browser language setting may or may not match up with the ethnicity of their name, but this is a fuzzy technique anyway.

Comment: I found that Google is chauvinist: more results come back for men than women because more men are in Google. The Facebook API is probably a lot more representative.

Answer (score 6):

Given your stated constraints, your best option is to re-phrase whatever it is you're writing to be [gender-neutral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-neutral_language) unless you *know* what gender they want to be called in each instance.

If writing in [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_neutrality_in_English), remember that [singular “they”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) is grammatically fine as a gender-neutral third-person singular pronoun.

A good example is the title of this question. As is currently:

```
    … mapping a person's name to his or her sex?
```

That would be less awkward if written:

```
    … mapping a person's name to their sex?
```

Comment: It's not quite "perfectly" grammatical.  Even the Wikipedia article admits that it has been used, particularly in the modern context, as a result of some writers' discomfort with the generic "he".  I don't have a big problem with writers that do this (although if gender-neutrality is really important, I prefer to reword the construct so I can use pronouns like "one"), but let's call it what it is.

Comment: I'd argue we're both right. All grammar, especially English grammar, has significant problems; but I'd say any definition of “perfect grammar” that actually applies to anything in English applies here too. Either the singular “they” is perfectly grammatical, or nothing in English is :-)

Comment: Of note, Grammar Girl (author Mignon Fogarty) has been leaning towards acceptance of the singular "they" for a while now.  

http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/he-they-generic-personal-pronoun.aspx

Answer (score 4):

It's also poor practice to assume that users must be male or female.  There are a small but significant number of "intersex" people, most of whom are heartily sick of not having a box to tick..
bignose: interesting on the "singular they".  I didn't realize it had such a long history.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a service, but a little app with a database:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/genderizer.aspx

And this tool is in german:
http://www.faq-o-matic.net/2011/06/01/zu-einem-vornamen-das-geschlecht-finden/

And another one in VB:
http://www.vbarchiv.net/tipps/tipp_1925-geschlecht-anhand-des-vornamens-ermitteln.html

I think in combination with some "Most used firstname in 2011" lists you should be able to build something decent.

Answer (score 4):

The python package [SexMachine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SexMachine/) will do that for you. Given any first name it returns if it's male, female or unisex. It relies on the data from the [gender.c](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/20260-gender-verification-by-forename-cmd-line-tool-db/) program by Jorg Michael.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you'll get from trying to automate it is a bunch of unhappy users. From that census data:

> JAMES, JOHN, ROBERT, MICHAEL, WILLIAM, DAVID, RICHARD, CHARLES, JOSEPH, THOMAS, CHRISTOPHER, DANIEL, PAUL, MARK, DONALD, GEORGE, KENNETH, STEVEN, EDWARD, BRIAN, RONALD, ANTHONY, KEVIN, JASON, MATTHEW, GARY, TIMOTHY, JOSE, LARRY, JEFFREY, FRANK, SCOTT, ERIC, STEPHEN, ANDREW, RAYMOND, GREGORY, JOSHUA, JERRY, DENNIS, WALTER, PATRICK, PETER, HAROLD, HENRY, CARL, ARTHUR, RYAN, JOE, JUAN, JACK, ALBERT, JUSTIN, TERRY, GERALD, KEITH, SAMUEL, WILLIE, LAWRENCE, ROY, BRANDON, ADAM, FRED, BILLY, LOUIS, JEREMY, AARON, RANDY, EUGENE, CARLOS, RUSSELL, BOBBY, VICTOR, MARTIN, JESSE, SHAWN, CLARENCE, SEAN, CHRIS, JOHNNY, JIMMY, ANTONIO, TONY, LUIS, MIKE, DALE, CURTIS, NORMAN, ALLEN, GLENN, TRAVIS, LEE, MELVIN, KYLE, FRANCIS, JESUS, RAY, JOEL, EDDIE, TROY, ALEXANDER, MARIO, FRANCISCO, MICHEAL, OSCAR, JAY, ALEX, JON, RONNIE, TOMMY, LEON, LEO, WESLEY, DEAN, DAN, LEWIS, COREY, MAURICE, VERNON, ROBERTO, CLYDE, SHANE, SAM, LESTER, CHARLIE, TYLER, GENE, BRETT, ANGEL, LESLIE, CECIL, ANDRE, ELMER, GABRIEL, MITCHELL, ADRIAN, KARL, CORY, CLAUDE, JAMIE, JESSIE, CHRISTIAN, LONNIE, CODY, JULIO, KELLY, JIMMIE, JORDAN, JAIME, CASEY, JOHNNIE, SIDNEY, JULIAN, DARYL, VIRGIL, MARSHALL, PERRY, MARION, TRACY, RENE, FREDDIE, AUSTIN, JACKIE, JOEY, EVAN, DANA, DONNIE, SHANNON, ANGELO, SHAUN, LYNN, CAMERON, BLAKE, KERRY, JEAN, IRA, RUDY, BENNIE, ROBIN, LOREN, NOEL, DEVIN, KIM, GUADALUPE, CARROLL, SAMMY, MARTY, TAYLOR, ELLIS, DALLAS, LAURENCE, DREW, JODY, FRANKIE, PAT, MERLE, TERRELL, DARNELL, TOMMIE, TOBY, VAN, COURTNEY, JAN, CARY, SANTOS, AUBREY, MORGAN, LOUIE, STACY, MICAH, BILLIE, LOGAN, DEMETRIUS, ROBBIE, KENDALL, ROYCE, MICKEY, DEVON, ASHLEY, CAREY, SON, MARLIN, ALI, SAMMIE, MICHEL, RORY, KRIS, AVERY, ALEXIS, GERRY, STACEY, CARMEN, SHELBY, RICKIE, BOBBIE, OLLIE, DENNY, DION, ODELL, MARY, COLBY, HOLLIS, KIRBY, CRUZ, MERRILL, LANE, CLEO, BLAIR, NUMBERS, CLAIR, BERNIE, JOAN, DOMINIQUE, TRISTAN, JAME, GALE, LAVERNE, ALVA, STEVIE, ERIN, AUGUSTINE, YOUNG, JOHNIE, ARIEL, DUSTY, LINDSEY, TRACEY, SCOTTIE, SANDY, SYDNEY, GAIL, DORIAN, LAVERN, REFUGIO, IVORY, ANDREA, SANG, DEON, CAROL, YONG, BERRY, TRINIDAD, SHIRLEY, MARIA, CHANG, ROSARIO, DANNIE, FRANCES, THANH, CONNIE, TORY, LUPE, DEE, SUNG, CHI, QUINN, MINH, THEO, LOU, CHUNG, VALENTINE, JAMEY, WHITNEY, SOL, CHONG, PARIS, OTHA, LACY, DONG, ANTONIA, KELLEY, CARROL, SHAYNE, VAL, JUDE, BRITT, HONG, LEIGH, GAYLE, JAE, NICKY, LESLEY, MAN, KASEY, JEWELL, PATRICIA, LAUREN, ELISHA, MICHAL, LINDSAY, and JEWEL

are all names that work for both males and females. If a girl's name is Robert and everyone, including your software, keeps on calling her a man, she'd be rather pissed.

Comment: Lets assume that there exists a girl called Mark (feel free to point one out). If I was her I'd be pissed off at my parents and not at Chas' software...

Comment: What if the software never calls her a man, but presents the "masculine" version of the UI? Or she's lumped in with men in an aggregate over a dataset used to develop marketing collateral? She might not even notice.

Comment: For a lot of these names i get a 100% certainty based on data from 500-1200 Facebook profiles of the given name.

http://api.genderize.io/?name=robert

http://api.genderize.io/?name=andrew

http://api.genderize.io/?name=john

Answer (score 3):

Although databases are probably the most practical solution, if you want to have some fun maybe you could try writing a neural net (or using a neural net library) that takes in the name and outputs one of those 3 options (F,M,A).

You could train it using the datasets that exist in the databases suggested by other answers, as well as with any other data you have.

This solution would allow you to handle names not specifically categorised previously, and also handle different languages. You might want to pass the language (if you know it) as an input to the neural net as well.

I don't know that I can say neural nets (or any other machine learning) would do a good job of categorising though.

Answer (score 3):

It's culture/region dependent: take Andrea, for Italians is only masculine, for Sweden is a female name while Andreas is for men; Shawn is ambiguous in English.
If a language has declination, like Latin or Russian, the final letters will change according to grammatical rules,

Another source of ambiguities is Family names identical to Personal names.

In my opinion it's impossibile to solve in general.

Comment: If OP had a companion variable indicating culture of origin, birthplace, nationality, whatever that would be useful. But he said he doesn't so you just have to make a statistically informed guess based on aggregates.

Answer (score 3):

The idea will clearly not work in most languages.

However if you could tell the nationality beforehand you could have more luck.
In most Slav languages (e.g. russian, polish, bulgarian) you could safely assume that all surnames ending with -va -cha -ska (-a in general are feminine) while -v -ch -shi are masculine.

In fact any surname has feminine and masculine form depending on the ending.
The same names used in other countries (e.g. US) might use only the masculine form though.

The same could be said for first names (-a -ya are feminine) but it is not 100% accurate.

But in general you would hardly get a library that is sufficiently accurate.

Comment: how is a surname masculine or feminine?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver My father's surname is Slavchev, and my mothers surname is Slavcheva. It is in fact the same surname bit it is spelled  differently for men and wemen. This is common for slavic names.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it, but IBM has a [Global Name Analytics](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/globalname/analytics/) library (for a price!) that seems pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

The Z Directory (at vettrasoft.com) has a C-language function, works something like so:

```
void func()
{
    char c = z_guess_sex_byfirstname ("Lon");
    switch(c)
    {
    case 'M': std::cout << "It's a boy!\n"; break;
    case 'F': std::cout << "It's a girl!\n"; break;
    case 'B': std::cout << "this name is for both sexes\n"; break;
    case '?': std::cout << "sex unknown sorry\n"; break;
    }
}
```

it's database driven, the table has something like 10,000+ names I think, but you need to
download and install the z directory (includes many other topo items like countries, geographical landmarks, airports, states, area codes, postal-zip codes, etc along with
c++ functions and objects to access the data). However the names are very English-language
oriented. The table is a work in progress and gradually updated.

Answer (score 1):

Name-gender maps can work but in multicultural countries it's more like guessing. I can give you one example: Marian in Polish is a typical masculine name, whereas the same name in Great Britain is a female name. In the era of people immigrating all over the world, I'm not sure such database would be very accurate. Good luck!

Comment: No, but so long as it is better than 50% it beats treating names as always masculine.

Comment: @Chas, so why cling to that false dichotomy? You have the option of gender-neutrality.

Comment: we even have 2 famous politics who have a second name 'maria' - 'mary' which would be classified in your database as feminine. just for the lols.

Comment: @JZ I am speaking of the firstname not the lastname (or vice versa for the cultures that do the reverse).

Comment: @bignose, the gender-neutral language looks weird and is convoluted, I would rather produce something that looks nicer when I can.  This is not communicated back to the individuals (if they even exist), so there is no chance of offense, I don't know why people are spending so much time arguing this instead of just providing links to databases if they know of a good one.

Comment: @Chas: second name != last name. like JFK :)

Answer (score 1):

Some cultures have unisex names - like mine. What do you do then? I think the answer is plain and simple - don't assume - you could cause offence. Just ask if its needed, otherwise gender neutrality.

Comment: The question already answered your answer: alex => "A", #ambiguous. Whether or not the question has an answer, your answer isn't it.

Comment: I disagree - My point is that all names are potentially ambiguous.

Comment: If the names are unisex then they would all be classified as A and I would go for gender neutrality, but if a name is predominately masculine or feminine I can use much more natural language.

Comment: I see what your reasoning is but I refer you to the latter comment.

Comment: I agree that all names are potentially ambiguous. The question already answered your answer. The question said to use "A" for ambiguous. You answer asked a question that the question already answered.

Comment: @Windows programmer If all names are potentially ambiguous, then the answer is f(x) = "A", which is the answer that Preet gave.

Comment: @Brian Campbell Yeah, but not all names are ambiguous.  Many have a high correlation with the person's sex.

Comment: But if you see a "Preet" on StackOverflow, it's probably a male.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not anymore. IBM [patented](http://yro.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=08/11/04/2221208) that idea a while ago.

So if you're looking for any level of flexability (something other than a list of names), you'll either have to (gasp!) ask the user, or simply pay IBM for the rights :)

In any case, such autodetection is annoying for many people who have gender-ambiguous names, or even just mean parents. Let's not make this any harder for them.

Comment: It looks like IBM patented choosing an avatar based on name.  Luckily that is not one of the applications I intend to use this for, so I am not violating their patent.  As for asking the user, that assumes I have users to ask as opposed to a list of names.  I have said repeatedly that there are no users, no interaction, and no messages going to the people who the names belong to.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free, but this is a nice library that I have used before:

> NetGender for .NET  allows you to
>   quickly and easily build Name
>   Verification, Parsing and Gender
>   Determination into your custom
>   applications. Accurately verify
>   whether a particular field contains a
>   valid individual or company. NetGender
>   uses a 100,000+, ethnically diverse,
>   Name Dictionary in combination with an
>   8,000+ Company Name Dictionary to
>   ensure precise gender determination.

http://www.softwarecompany.com/dotnet/netgender.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting that you say you have birth date. That could help. I've seen databases of histories of name popularity.

In the film Splash (1984), it was funny that Darryl Hannah's character chooses the name "Madison" from a Madison Avenue street sign, because obviously "Madison" is not a girl's name.

24 years later, Madison is the 4th most popular name for girl babies!

---

[Name history from the gov't.](http://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/babyname.cgi) (Check out Mary's sad decline through the last 100 years.)

---

When I wrote to the White House as a child, Richard Nixon (or, perhaps a secretary) responded to me with some photos of the historic place, addressed to "Miss Rhett Anderson." "Miss Rhett?" It doesn't even make sense! Can we REALLY not tell the difference between Clark Gable's Rhett (with a mustache, in Gone With The Wind!) and Vivian Lee's Scarlett? I shall never forgive him, despite Neil Young's assurance that "even Richard Nixon has got soul."

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure no such service could exist with an acceptable level of accuracy. Here are the problems which I think are insurmountable:

- There are plenty of names which are for both men and women.
- There's a lot of different names in this world, even if you only consider one country.
- There is the "A Boy Named Sue" issue, raised so eloquently by Johnny Cash :-)

Comment: A good database would have the percentage male/female for androgynous names by region and when the sample was taken, etc.

Comment: What about languages such as Japanese?  I'm learning Japanese so I might be wrong here, but names <-> Kanji are not a straight forward relationships, there has been puns and misunderstanding on "what" kanji makes up a person's name.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://genderchecker.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at my python gender detection project https://github.com/muatik/genderizer

It tries to detect authors' genders looking their names and/or sample text(for example tweets) of them.

And it also supports mongodb, memcached for performance.

Comment: Seems good but if you need it to be "country of origin" aware see gender.c or genderize.io below

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a programming problem - it comes down to getting a probability table.

AFAIK there are no public databases in distilled forms. You could either build this from census data, or buy the data from someone.

For example, this is [someone who sells the probability table for Canada](http://www.gpeters.com/name-gender/).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it is a generally bad idea to determine sex from an individuals name. A lot of names are intersexual (good grief, is this even a word ?? :-), and also they may be one sex in one culture and another in another.

A few stupid examples, just a few that came to mind (from my part of the world, CE)

Vanja - female, in eastern countries from here, mostly male
Alex - intersex (short for Sandra, female, and Sandro, male)
Robin - in western cultures, can be both

In some parts of the world, a persons sex can be determined by looking at how the name ends. For example, Marija, Sandra, Ivana, Petra, Sara, Lucija, Ana - you can see that most of these female names end in "ja" or "ra". There are other examples as well.

Still, I think it's better just to ask the user for sex.

Answer (score 0):

Got [this](http://www.hackerfactor.com/GenderGuesser.html) from  hacker news [discussion](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=608057) about this

Answer (score 0):

I know of no such service, however ..

- you could start with a [raw list of person names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803628/raw-list-of-person-names/1803635#1803635) or
- guess gender according to some rules (e.g. -o => male, -ela, -a => female)

In some countries (e.g. germany) the name a person can be given is limited by law - maybe there are some publications concerning that matter, which could be harvested (but I don't know of any in the moment).

Answer (score 0):

I know of no such service.  You can perhaps find the data you are looking for, however.  The US government publishes data about the prevalence of names and the gender of the person they're attached to.  The Social Security Administration has such a [page](http://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/), and the census may as well, but I haven't taken the time to look.  Perhaps other world governments do similar things.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is make a hack which takes the name and searches it against the facebook api. Then looks at the resulting users and count how many of them are female or male. You then can return a percentage. Not so insurmountable anymore. :)

Answer (score -2):

Just ask people, and if they are nice they will give you their 'M's or 'F's , and if they are not then give'em an 'A' .

Comment: I am not in communication with the people whose names I want to map.

Answer (score -2):

I think it will be hard to find libraries or databases that covers more than one (or a limited few) cultures. For instance, here in Sweden the name "Maria" is strongly identified as a female name, while (to the best of my understanding) that connection is not at all as strong in spanish-speaking countries.

Comment: Maria is a female name in Spain

Comment: Google for José Maria and you will find plenty of men carrying the name Maria. Perhaps not as their primary name, but still.

Comment: Multuple databases/libraries are fine.  My assumption is that such a search would be O(1), so even a hundred searches would be trivial.

Comment: I'm Hispanic and Maria is STRONGLY associated with females. not to say there aren't Jose Maria's out there, but it's not common at all.

Comment: Italy also has some males with Maria as a middle name. English speaking countries have some females with Jean as a first or second name (pronounced differently from the French name Jean). English has Karen as a female name. English vs. English on Leslie. Databases are going to have a lot of A's.

Answer (score -3):

Dont bother attempting to determine a persons sex from an entered name. When you get it wrong your going to really piss someone off, letting users enter their sex is simple so you may as well let them enter it.

Comment: That would work if I were designing a form to interact with people, but that is not what is going on.

Answer (score -3):

Plus I don't know but what about Asian language, Arabic, and/or one of the thousands of languages out there.

I mean sure I could see a database of names with the percentage that was male versus female, along with additional information such as region, country, and so forth.  But ultimately in the end it would be quite a complicated and large database to be able to deal with all of the possible name in the world.

Plus how to deal with names that aren't in the database? etc....