# Is there a service that can tell whether a given name is Male or Female?

Tags: api, social-networking, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anyone know of a good library for mapping a person's name to his or her sex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818203/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-library-for-mapping-a-persons-name-to-his-or-her-sex)

I am looking for a service that can tell me if a given name is Male or Female. I have a list of names (possibly geo-tagged) and I want to filter out the Males/Females out of them. Any thoughts?