# Is there a package to determine gender from English first names?

Tags: r

I am curious to know whether there is a package or method for **R** to guess gender from first names.

<del>I am thinking of running it on the U.S. Congress as a test.</del>

**I need this to work over several European languages.**

<del>CRAN does not have such a package.</del>

**CRAN has the gender package, but it works only on English names.**

**Issue solved by the [genderizeR](https://github.com/kalimu/genderizeR) package.** See links in my self-answer.

Comment: not aware of an r package... but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818203/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-library-for-mapping-a-persons-name-to-his-or-her-sex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [this discussion](https://github.com/rOpenGov/finpar/issues/2) on Finnish names, I came across the fantastic [genderizeR](https://github.com/kalimu/genderizeR) package, which looks into an online database to determine gender from names in several languages.

Solved!

Answer (score 6):

There is now a package on CRAN for specifically for this: [gender](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gender/index.html)

From the description:

> Encodes gender based on names and dates of birth, using either the
>   Social Security Administration's data set of first names by year of
>   birth or the Census Bureau data from 1789 to 1940, both from the
>   United States of America. By using these data sets instead of lists of
>   male and female names, this package is able to more accurately guess
>   the gender of a name, and it is able to report the probability that a
>   name was male or female.

It also has a very helpful [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gender/vignettes/predicting-gender.html) demonstrating typical uses.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the answer is "no," but you could still use R to analyze this. Obviously it would be a probabilistic type of answer since some names are ambiguous or unique. [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818203/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-library-for-mapping-a-persons-name-to-his-or-her-sex) has some helpful suggestions but links are out of date. US census data is a good place to start. From the 2000 United States census, you can find name directories and metadata at http://www.census.gov/genealogy/www/data/1990surnames/names_files.html. 
Some interesting issues are discussed in http://www.census.gov/srd/papers/pdf/rr97-2.pdf and http://www.census.gov/population/www/documentation/twps07/twps07.pdf.

Answer (score 4):

Please don't accept this as an answer as it is based on other's answers and links.  I have added this function to the [qdap package](https://github.com/trinker/qdap) as it fits the package.

```
library(qdap)

name2sex(qcv(mary, jenn, linda, JAME, GABRIEL, OLIVA, 
    tyler, jamie, JAMES, tyrone, cheryl, drew))

name2sex(qcv(mary, jenn, linda, JAME, GABRIEL, OLIVA, 
    tyler, jamie, JAMES, tyrone, cheryl, drew), FALSE)

name2sex(qcv(mary, jenn, linda, JAME, GABRIEL, OLIVA, 
    tyler, jamie, JAMES, tyrone, cheryl, drew), FALSE, TRUE)

name2sex(qcv(mary, jenn, linda, JAME, GABRIEL, OLIVA, 
    tyler, jamie, JAMES, tyrone, cheryl, drew), TRUE, FALSE)


## > name2sex(qcv(mary, jenn, linda, JAME, GABRIEL, OLIVA, 
## +     tyler, jamie, JAMES, tyrone, cheryl, drew))
##  [1] F F F M M F M F M M F M
## Levels: F M

## > name2sex(qcv(mary, jenn, linda, JAME, GABRIEL, OLIVA, 
## +     tyler, jamie, JAMES, tyrone, cheryl, drew), FALSE)
##  [1] B    <NA> F    B    B    F    B    B    B    M    F    B   
## Levels: B F M

## > name2sex(qcv(mary, jenn, linda, JAME, GABRIEL, OLIVA, 
## +     tyler, jamie, JAMES, tyrone, cheryl, drew), FALSE, TRUE)
##  [1] B F F B B F B B B M F B
## Levels: B F M

## > name2sex(qcv(mary, jenn, linda, JAME, GABRIEL, OLIVA, 
## +     tyler, jamie, JAMES, tyrone, cheryl, drew), TRUE, FALSE)
##  [1] F    <NA> F    M    M    F    M    F    M    M    F    M   
## Levels: F M
```

**Edit**- I added a `fuzzy.match` argument to attempt to guess gender for non recognized names based on fuzzy matching, though this is computationally expensive.

Comment: I won't accept it as an answer but I have +1'd it. I'm a big fan of your package, it's teaching me lots about topics like sentiment analysis. Thanks for your contribution, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon your implementation ideas, the `plyr` package tutorial has a [good data set](http://plyr.had.co.nz/09-user/):

> Baby names Top 1000 male and female baby names in the US, from 1880 to
>   2008. 258,000 records (1000 * 2 * 129) But only four variables: year, name, sex and percent.

Comment: I don't believe this is in [plyr's data sets](https://github.com/hadley/plyr/tree/master/data).

Comment: Fair point - it's in the tutorial, not the official package.  This is downloadable via the link above.