# Twitter Data Mining for Gender and/or Age with R

Tags: r, twitter

I was wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to mine Twitter data for age and/or gender. So, to be able to tell what age someone that tweets about something is and what gender. Possibly by using R. 
If you know that this can be done, do you suggest any resources that could help me?

Thank you

Comment: If you post sample data I have a few ideas to handle this programatically.

Comment: This looks relevant: [Estimate Age from First Name](http://rforwork.info/2013/07/29/estimate-age-from-first-name/)

Answer (score 2):

There's a few hints at guessing gender based on names and keywords [in this paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2108098). Age-guessing is going to be pretty hard, unless you are planning to use very large age groups on very large data.

I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802704/r-is-there-a-package-to-determine-gender-from-english-first-names) some time ago, and there is now a `name2sex` function in the [`qdap` package](https://github.com/trinker/qdap). Check it out (note: the package maintainer is also on StackOverflow).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Tyler :)