# Method to find gender of a username - with or without dictionary

Tags: python, text

I'm trying to find a way to do both actions:
1) Retrieving a gender from a name
2) Retrieving a gender from a username (similar to the previous one but different)

I reviewed some methods how to do 1) (including: [Does anyone know of a good library for mapping a person's name to his or her gender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818203/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-library-for-mapping-a-persons-name-to-his-or-her-gen)), and might do it, but I have a problem to do the second:

Let's say that I have a dictionary containing all names split to female or male. Now I want to take a username and try to see whether the username contains one of these names (because username can contain more than just the first name itself) - what's the best way to do it? It seems not efficient to go over all the dict keys and look for them in the username one by one... There must be an optimized method...

Hope that I explained myself clearly, any help would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: If you have some working code, this isn't the place. You're asking for optimization, so go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can go for binary search because its sorted: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm its O(log n) instead of O(n)

Comment: that's not how a dictionary works.  A key is mapped to a value via its hash.  Lookups are in constant time.  So `my_gender_dict.get('bob')` takes (about) the same amount of time to find bob's gender whether `my_gender_dict` contains 10 keys or 10 thousand.

Comment: Also, you can only assign gender with a certain probability, not by looking it up in a dictionary.

Comment: The issue is that I have no problem in looking for a specific key, I have a problem to see if the string I have CONTAINS one of the keys (e.g. username like greatjohn contains john) and I have to go key by key to find that...

Comment: @user3017075 What if it contained more than one key: "Alexander" is "Alex" (A), "Al", (M), "Lex" (M), "Xander" (M)... Or someone called "James Kelly" has a username of "jkelly" - are they then female - what about "Sarah Martin" etc... Look up about `trie`s - they might be able to assist with reducing the lookups... but then not sure where you'll go from there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary will only help in the case that the user name (or name) is an exact match. It may be best to use a simple list:

Make certain that the names you include in `girl_names` and `boy_names` are fully gender-specific. (For instance, Ben wouldn't work, since both men and women could go by Ben.) Also make sure that the lists don't have any repeated partial names, E.g. "Al" and "Albert".

`girl_names` = Large set of likely female-only names, all lower-case.

`boy_names` = Large set of likely male-only names, all lower-case.

`user_name` = The user name you're looking up.

```
def name_gender(user_name, boy_names=None, girl_names=None):
    uname = user_name.lower()
    girliness = 0
    for girl_name in girl_names:
        if girl_name in uname:
            girliness += 1
    boyishness = 0
    for boy_name in boy_names:
        if boy_name in uname:
            boyishness += 1
    if boyishness > girlishness: return 'Male'
    if girlishness > boyishness: return 'Female'
    return 'Androgynous'
```

This function is only a loose proxy for real intended user name gender. Lists of common names are available from various web sites, and can also be obtained from the Census information.

Comment: I can see that resulting in a lot of *Androgynous* results...