# Classification of gender for given names

Tags: classification, text-classification

after some research I could not find yet a suitable open source library or software I can use to classify by most likely gender a long table of first names I have.
For my application I have a set of first names from many different countries, and many of them are also pretty exotic.

For example, when I tried to use Genderize I could get only 1/8 of the names classified, while the remaining are labeled as Unknown (I made sure that the format is correct, no lower/upper case ambiguity, etc..).

Any advise would be appreciated. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does anyone know of a good library for mapping a person's name to his or her gender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818203/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-library-for-mapping-a-persons-name-to-his-or-her-gen)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the best I could find was really just do it manually looking up names from google or dedicated websites such as https://namepedia.org. I am afraid there is no automated solution for my use case. This mostly for the following reasons:

- Many names are somewhat archaic (I could not even recognise several names of my own nationality)
- Many names were truncated to form nicknames or had two nearby letters swapped: here a LUT approach would fail and rather one would need a score from a model
- There were several names not based on Roman alphabet but where the mapping into roman characters produced some ambiguities I guess

For those curious of the original dataset, this is part of a Kaggle challenge (Spaceship Titanic, https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/spaceship-titanic).